# MacOS Server DHCP lease duration change

Tags: macos, network, server.app

Running MacOS Server 5.2 on El Capitan. I'd like to change the DHCP server's lease duration.  I'd like to use 8 hours but the GUI only gives me a choice of 1 hour, or 1 Day, or higher.

Can anyone help me with a terminal command to achieve this please?

I've found `sudo serveradmin settings dhcp | grep lease` which lets me see DHCP settings, but I just cannot work out how to change the lease period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First enter - to get an overview and the appropriate array_idUUID:

```
sudo serveradmin settings dhcp
```

Then (with the proper array_idUUID)

```
sudo serveradmin settings dhcp:subnets:_array_id:array_idUUID:lease_max = 28800
```

Example:

```
sudo serveradmin settings dhcp:subnets:_array_id:A387646D-BBC1-88CD-993E-2D36E15C5089:lease_max = 28800
```

Then restart the DHCP service:

```
sudo serveradmin stop dhcp
sudo serveradmin start dhcp
```

Check the new settings with `sudo serveradmin settings dhcp`

Comment: Thanks klanomath, that's exactly what I needed.  Afterwards - the check reflected the change within terminal.app and the GUI also reflected it.  Many thanks!